# MySQL fetching a key value pair which are in two different columns

Tags: mysql, ibatis

Table1 : Has 3 columns say id, key & value.

```
+----+-----+-------+
| ID | KEY | VALUE |
+----+-----+-------+
| 1  | 1   | 1     |
| 2  | 1   | 2     |
| 3  | 2   | 1     |
| 4  | 2   | 2     |
| 5  | 3   | 1     |
| 6  | 3   | 2     |
| 7  | 4   | 1     |
| 8  | 4   | 2     |
| 9  | 5   | 1     |
| 10 | 5   | 2     |
+----+-----+-------+
```

This table key and value both can be repeated but the combination of both is unique.

If I want to query for multiple rows based on the key value pair and **NOT** on id. How can I do that ?

**NOTE**: I know I can do this

```
SELECT * from Table1 
WHERE (key=1 AND value=2) OR 
      (key=1 AND value=1) OR 
      (key=5 AND value=1);
```

I was hope to something much better and concise as I have approximately 40K key value pairs which I need to query for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other proper way than what you are already doing. You should rather compare on the unique column, which in you case is `ID`. yes you can shorten it using a `IN` operator to compare row constructors saying

```
SELECT * from Table1 
WHERE (`key`, `value`) IN ((1,2),(1,1),(5,1));
```

See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) for more information on the same.

Comment: Thanks a bunch exactly what I was looking for ! Appreciate your help.